# Can roads be built with fish before my turn?

Tags: catan-traders-and-barbarians

The instruction card for using fish states, “You may *immediately* build 1 road for free.”  Does this mean I can build the road immediately, or do I need to wait for my turn as stated in the game instructions?

Answer (score 1):

You can only spend fish on your turn. From [the rulebook](https://www.catan.com/sites/default/files/2021-06/catan-t_b_2020_rule_book_200820.pdf)

> During your turn, you can discard fish tokens to take certain actions.

The “immediately” on the reminder card doesn’t change this. It just means that you build the road immediately upon spending the fish tokens. It’s an unnecessary clarification, as all the actions you spend fish to do happen “immediately” upon spending the fish.